# When creating an array of comboboxes two combox appear to have same getID

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, combobox, itemlistener

I have created a GUI where you can add extra combobox when addcombobox button is clicked. I have created an array of comboboxes and calling the additemlistener by using the following:

```
count1++;
MyItemListener2 actionListener2 = new MyItemListener2();
fruits[count1].addItemListener(actionListener2);
```

and have also implemented class of name MyItemListener2, but when the addcombobox button is clicked twice, two times comboboxes are created with same getID as if they appear to be same comboboxes with all the same properties.

How can i differentiate the two created comboboxes?